# How to remove elements from a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to get a piece of code to work but I'm not a jquery guy so please bear with me.

`I have an outer DIV ($scope)`. It contains all kinds of inputs.

I find all the entries for each input type and filter them to get the ones with values. These are stored in $entries.

```
$inputs contains all the inputs regardless of type or status.
```

What I'm trying to do is `remove $entries from $inputs` to leave the difference.

It doesn't work, and at the moment I'm not getting any errors firing back, so nothing to go on.

My first thought is that jquery is unable to match the elements in one list with the other as it just holds an index, not the actual object. This could be totally wrong (please refer back to line 1).

Either way, I need to find a way of getting all elements and segegating them into 2 bits - those with values and those without.

All help appreciated.

```
    function inputLoaded(isPostback) {
            if (typeof Page_Validators !== "undefined") {

$scope = $(".active-step:first");
                $inputs = $scope.find(inputs);
            $cb = $scope.find(checkboxes).filter(":checked");
            $rb = $scope.find(radios).filter(":checked");
            $sb = $scope.find(selects).filter(function () { return $(this).val() !== "None"; });
            $ta = $scope.find(textareas).filter(function () { return $(this).val(); });
            $tb = $scope.find(textboxes).filter(function () { return $(this).val(); });
            $entries = $cb.add($rb).add($sb).add($ta).add($tb);

            // Do things with $entries here

            // Get elements that have not got entries
            $el = $inputs.remove($entries);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `$inputs.filter(input => !$entries.contains(input))`?

Comment: @gcampbell - why choose es6 when OP isn't using it?

Comment: `$input.not($entries)` would be simpler.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I just think in ES6, it's closer to other languages. ES5 version would be `$inputs.filter(function (input) { return $entries.indexOf(input) === -1; }` (if that's how jQuery element lists work)

Comment: @gcampbell - I'd just be careful with using arrow functions as jquery callbacks, as it changes the reference to this.

Comment: You guys lost me at ES6, however the not function does work and it's simple.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm probably shooting myself in the foot with not knowing jQuery here, but I was thinking of Array#filter`.

Comment: @gcampbell - You're right. Using a function as an argument they both work in almost identical ways. It's just `this` is normally the current element in jquery callbacks.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - you have the correct answer - would you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method can take a jQuery object whose contents will be excluded from the jQuery object you apply it to. It looks exactly like what you're looking for:

```
// Get elements, excluding entries.
$el = $input.not($entries);
```